# How the heck to remove a block from a Hero web-part?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Hero web part with five tiles. I simply want to delete contents of one of the tiles and end up with four tiles. I could replace the contents of a tile by editing it, but I just want it to disappear. So how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Please following steps:**

1.Go to the Site Page as site admin

2.Click "**Edit**" to edit page

[image]

3.Select the **Hero web part** and click "**Edit web part**"

[image]

4.On the Hero panel, you can choose Layout Type. For example, I choose the "**Foue titles**" Layout.

[image]

5.Republish page

[image]

Here is an article to help you make better use of Hero web part.

- [Use the Hero web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-hero-web-part-d57f449b-19a0-4b0d-8ce3-be5866430645)

Comment: Thanks. I wish I had asked more clearly.  In your example, the fifth "flower" tile is hiding and could be restored if necessary.
I want to KEEP all five tiles, but I want the "flower" tile to be empty rather than the tiles reducing from 5 to 4. I see I can rearrange and reduce the number of tiles, but can I DELETE the "flower" tile?

Comment: Hi Bruce M. Based on my research, we could not hide hide the picture in the Hero web part, it is by design. Therefore, we recommend either not adding the fifth picture in the Hero web part, or replacing the fifth picture with a blank picture.